# Function returning multiple values in R

Tags: r, function

Say I have a function

```
f <- function(){

  # do things

  return(list(zoo = x, vector = y, integer = z))
}
```

When I call this function using

```
result <- f()
```

Is there any way to call the return variables explicitly? Ie do I have to call it using

```
vara <- result$vara
varb <- result$varb
varc <- result$varc
```

Since if this function returns a lot of data types (whether it be data frames, zoo's, vectors, etc). The reason I dont want to bind into data frame is because not all variables are of the same length.

Comment: Can you be a little more precise so you don't want to use result$vara and result["vara"] then what type you want

Comment: Well, you can attach it if you really want to go that way.

Comment: Like in some languages you can just do [x,y,z] = f(). Its clean and doesnt take up many lines. When I have to define the variables as above, its always written as result$<blah>

Comment: Yeah, I like that syntax too, but I think it's not available in R. The ugly workaround is attach(setNames(f(),c("a","b")))

Comment: If you only need one item,  `vara=f()$vara`  will work.

Comment: @bob  The reason some of us don't like that ` [x y z]=F()`  is that it's a pain when you only want `z` . Personally I think `R` 's paradigm of returning a single object, which can be a list,  is much cleaner than MATLAB's  kludge of a strictly-ordered collection of returned objects.

Answer (score 4):

### Use `with` or `within`

If the problem is just that you don't like typing `result`, then you can use `with` or `within` to access elements inside the list.

```
with(result, vara + varb * varc)
```

This is a good, standard way of doing things.

### Use `list2env`

You could copy the variables from the list using `list2env`.

```
 list2env(result, parent.frame())
```

This is slightly risky because you have two copies of your variables which may introduce bugs.  If you are including the code in a package, R CMD check will give you warnings about global variables.

### Use `attach`

This is a really bad idea (don't do this).

`attach` is like a permanent version of `with`.  If you

```
attach(result)
```

then you can access each element without the `result$` prefix.  But it will lead to many horrendous, obscure bugs in your code when an error gets thrown before you detach it, and then you attach it a second time and drown in a variable-scope-swamp.